# 'Android SDK "Android API 29 Platform" is not found on the disk or corrupted.' in Android Studio

Tags: flutter, dart, android-studio

I used Android Studio some years ago. After that time I initialized Windows 10 once and used the migration tool to change my SSD. This time, I needed Android Studio once more for making a Flutter app, but it was gone(I don't remember removing it myself).

So I installed Android Studio once more and Flutter once more.
But after I make a new flutter project by Android Studio, I can see a blue ribbon at the top of the editor that says 'Android SDK "Android API 29 Platform" is not found on the disk or corrupted.'

I try something to solve that. :

- Install Android API 29(Android 10.0("Q")) with the Android SDK manager = not works
- Click the Configure...(on the blue ribbon) and Click "Download Android SDK" and go on = not works
- Uninstall the Andriod Studio with uninstaller(remove all settings) and remove all of the left(%userprofile%.gradle, appdata\local\Android, program files\Android) of it and reinstall Android Studio = not works

Everything is not working. I found one who has a problem like me, but Its solution is not work for me.

How to solve it?

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.3324], locale ko-KR)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[X] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at .\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.
[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.11.29)
[√] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.76.2)
[√] Connected device (2 available)
[√] Network resources
```

Comment: see this [GuideLink](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fix-sdk-tools-directory-is-missing-error-in-android-studio/)

Comment: can you share screenshots please

Comment: I solved it with @Mohammad Mirshahbazi 's help. I can't take it. sorry

Comment: Tools –> SDK manager –> SDK tools.  Deselect the Hide obsolete packages option on the right bottom and further install Android SDK Tools(obsolete). A new folder named Tools is now generated in the SDK directory.

Answer (score 4):

Settings > Language & frameworks > Android SDK > select Android 10.0 (API Level 29), then click OK.

[image]

then go to file > project structure

1. in project select sdk Android API 33
2. in modules select the purple folders and select Module SDK: Android 33.

These steps solved the problem for me

Comment: Solved mine as well, thank you :))

Answer (score 3):

Just to add some steps in @Ali Al-Amrad's Answer. in The Project Structure => Modules => and select Android API 29 from the Drop down list. If That is not present there then you click on Add to download that . [image]

Comment: This does not work!

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

To fix the problem, I installed a previous version of Android Studio [Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 2] from [Android Studio Archives](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive) which worked fine and I never saw that error again.

I've done everything suggested on the internet to fix this problem and that error didn't go away until I downgraded the Android Studio version.

I had Android Studio [Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 1] which is currently the latest stable version when you try and download it. I am not sure if it's a bug in that version or what but that fixed it for me.

Comment: Thank you. The solution for me was actually even easier. Just turn off "Enable new UI" in File->Settings->Appearance & Behavior->New UI. After that restart Android Studio and then turn on "Enable new UI" and restart again. The error should be gone by now.

Comment: +1 to this error first occurring in Giraffe 2022.3.1 Patch 1. Downgrading fixes the issue. Enabling / disabling the new UI as @jestrabikr mentioned has no effect, likely coincidence.

Answer (score 2):

Try this steps :

[image: Project Structure]

1 - go to project structure
2- select Modules
3- choose your -android
and change  or Add SDK of android api 29 or the latest one such Android API 33

press OK , and close your project and reopen it .
this is solved with me .

Comment: This does not work!

Answer (score 2):

In my case to fix it, I just went to :
**File** > **Project Structure** > **SDKS**
and click on the cross icon to add new Android SDK:

[image: Android studio project sdk add panel]

Then locate my SDK folder:

[image: Locate SDK folder]

And create a new SDK and selecting the build target:

[image]

After that I get an error that said 'Cannot Detect SDK':

[image]

But even with that error I get a new Platform added:

[image]

Then I just delete the old one and rename the new, to get rid of the '(2)':

[image]

I **Apply** the changes and when i get back to project, the error goes away!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is a problem with New UI Android Studio I assume. The **fix is very easy**, just turn off `Enable new UI` in `File->Settings->Appearance & Behavior->New UI`. After that restart Android Studio and then turn on `Enable new UI` and restart again.

The error should be gone by now.

Answer (score 1):

in my case, I just reinstall Android Studio and then download again SDK Platform. ***File > Settings > Language & Frameworks > SDK 29 (don't forget to check on checkbox "Android SDK Platform 29")***.
[image: _]

And then restart Android Studio using Invalidate Chaces. ***File > Invalidate Chaces (and check all checkbox)***

[image: _]

Answer (score 0):

Go to file > Project Structure> and choose the Android API 29 platform from the drop down menu and you are set to go.

Answer (score 0):

I had two separate Android Studio installs upgraded to 2022.3.1 Giraffe, and both had their Android SDKs corrupted as a result.

The only solution that consistently worked was deleting the Android SDK folder and redownloading everything from scratch (in my case for Android API 34) using Tools -> SDK Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Delete everything related to Android Studio (Android, .jdk and other AS related folders ) including the app itself and download the Android Studion from [ToolBox](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/)
That will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I could solved it
go to file > Project Structure in tab SDKs correct android SDK home path

Answer (score -1):

Most probably you have to download the Android SDK tool (Obsolete) from the SDK Manager

Comment: This is wrong, the sdk tool has nothing to do with it.

Comment: well if you are so smart then you should have known by now that , the issue you face will not affect the development process at all : )